# How to get multiple td selection in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I output a calendar in a table row. Every td is a single day. I need to open a form once I do this operation:
click on one td, move the cursor to left or right, click on another td.
I have to open my form and insert start_date and end_date according to selected cell.

I think that once I click on first cell, I have to create a function that add a class "selected" to each td I hover, then on second click, I have to get all cell with class "selected".

What do you think?

Comment: if you have tried something, please include your code

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest two ways of solving your task:

1. Use Vuetify and its [date and time pickers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers).
2. Writing from scratch.

Now, lets talk about the second one. Your calendar is a 2D matrix (2d array), each cell has its own unique index `x` or `[x,y]`coordinates. When the user selects first `td`-cell and the second one you just need to loop from minimum index to maximum index and add `selected` class to `td`-cells.

Assume that this is your calendar:

```
(1)(2)(3)
(4)(5)(6)
(7)(8)(9)
```

If the user selected `(4)` and `(8)` you just need to loop from 4th index to 8th and add `selected` class. On the other hand, if the user chooses `(8)` and than `(4)` you just need to swap them and loop from minimal value to maximum adding to each `td`-cell `selected` class.